# Zen-Cart Checkout page null

Tags: php, payment-gateway, credit-card, payment-processing, zen-cart

I am getting error on checkout page:

> Your card has been declined. Please re-enter your card information,
>   try another card, or contact the store owner for assistance.

and the URL of the page is : `site.com/index.php?main_page=checkout&fecaction=null`

I am using Securepay payment module and credit card is verified with them.

Comment: That looks like the service saying "you do not have enough money in this account for the payment". An obvious thing to check is decimal points in the wrong place, e.g. you tried to take `$1000` instead of `$10.00`

Comment: I am using a test payment with a test card detail provided by the Securepay.

Comment: Is this a question related to programming???

Comment: No..Its related to Politicians !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing, you need to set SecurePay in test mode (under admin->modules->payment).  Otherwise a test card will not be accepted.

Comment: I am using the securepay module in testing mode.